# jquery hover on submenu with sliding efekt

Tags: jquery, hover, slidetoggle, submenu

I am looking for solutions on my problem. I would like to make an animation (slide up, slide down) on hover but I cant to resolve it. If you take a look on [this](http://tnabytek.webovy-servis.cz/) page it is a image router. This is clear CSS solution, works without JS but I wanna add sliding animation... If mouseenter on image submenu should slide up from the bottom and when mouseover submenu should slide down. Thanks a lot for your tips how to resolve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

**In your case** this would be a solution:

Remove `#menu ul li:hover ul { display: block; z-index: 300; }` in your css.

```
$(function(){

    $('#menu ul li').mouseenter(function() {

        $(this).find('ul').css({'z-index':'300'}).slideDown();

    });

    $('#menu ul li').mouseleave(function() {

        $(this).find('ul').css({'z-index':'0'}).slideUp();

    });

});
```

**Original:**

This is very easy to understand if you are new to jQuery:

```
$(function(){

    $('#selector').mouseenter(function() {

        $('#submenu').slideUp();

    });

    $('#selector').mouseleave(function() {

        $('#submenu').slideDown();

    });

});
```

jQuery checks if you enter or leave an element with the mouse with e.g. [.mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [.mouseleave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/). Now you can use [.slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) [.slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) to slide another element.
Be sure to remove the css hover effect first and set the element you want to slide to `display: none;`

Comment: But i want to write a universal code for all 8 boxes. This will slide all submenus at once. This is main problem for me

Comment: i will look into that for you tommorrow, check back to your question in time :)